# Bulk Updates in React Native using Realm

Tags: react-native, realm

What is the most efficient way to do bulk updates in Realm using React Native?

For example, I want to query for some records in a particular Realm object that satisfy a particular filter, and then update a property on each record returned from the query.

I've seen several Swift and Java examples here on SO, but I believe the method chaining used there is not available for React Native, though I may be mistaken.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as you are updating all of your objects in a single write transaction it should be pretty quick to loop through and update each object. There is currently no optimized batch update operation.

Comment: I think this answer is still current: https://github.com/realm/realm-js/issues/808